# Removing VM blob from Azure storage account

Tags: azure

I created a few VMs sharing one storage account in Azure using Resource Group deployment model.

When I remove a VM from the resource group, is its VHD removed automatically from the storage account or I need to do something extra to free the space?

Thank you.

Comment: Ok, it seems the blob isn't cleaned up automatically so should be taken care of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I remove a VM from the resource group, is it's VHD removed
>   automatically from the storage account or I need to do something extra
>   to free the space?

In Azure ARM module, if we delete the VM via the portal, the VM's VHD still store in the storage account, and the VM's NIC, NSG, public IP address and others will not delete automatically. 
If you want to delete the VM and the VHD, you should delete the VHD via the portal or PowerShell command `Remove-AzureStorageBlob` manually.

```
PS > $RGName = "jason"
PS > $SAName = "jasondisks709"
PS > $ConName = "vhds"
PS > $TempObj = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject
PS > $TempObj |Add-Member -Name BlobName -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $null
PS > $TempObj |Add-Member -Name LeaseState -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $null
PS > $Keylist = Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $RGName -StorageAccountName $SAName
PS > $Key = $Keylist[0].Value
PS > $Ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $SAName -StorageAccountKey $Key
PS > $List = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Blob *.vhd -Container $ConName -Context $Ctx
PS > $List | ForEach-Object { $TempObj.BlobName = $_.Name; $TempObj.LeaseState = $_.ICloudBlob.Properti
es.LeaseState; $TempObj }

BlobName                 LeaseState
--------                 ----------
VM120170119085610.vhd        Leased
centos20170119090103.vhd     Leased
```

The Blob name, first part is VM's name, other is the date, so you can find the blob's name you need.

Comment: Yep I experimentally learned that. Thank you. Is there any way I can give blob a name when deploying the VM? That way at least I will know which blob belongs to which machines when removing it automatically.

Comment: @Alex we can't name the VM's VHD by default, but we can list the VM's information, in this way, we can find the VHD's name. If the VM deleted, we can list all blobs and the blobs status, in this way, we can find the blob's name you need, I will add a script to list all blobs with powershell.

Comment: It seems like with the classic deployment model you get option to delete the VHD when you delete a VM. So odd they didn't add this functionality to the new deployment model.

Comment: @Alex I had update the answer, in this way we can find the blob's name.